# Edit one value in a multi-value attribute javascript

Tags: javascript, search, attributes

I set up a search function for a content system.
The user is able to publish and unpublish his elements.
Every element has two keywords + the condition state = 3 keywords for the search in sum.

Every element has an attribute namend "data-meta" in which the three keywords are stored.

eg.

```
data-meta="banana blue public"
```

How can i edit the last value "public", if the user wants to unpublish his element and set it to private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually altering how you store these values, such as creating custom attributes like

```
data-keyone="banana" data-keytwo="blue" data-state="public"
```

you can pull the value of the attribute, split it, modify the third element, join it, then set the attribute value to the new string.

Starting with this:

```
<myelement id="example" data-meta="banana blue public">
```

Pull the value:

```
var oElem = document.getElementById("example");
var strTemp = oElem.getAttribute("data-meta"); //javascript
var strTemp = $('myelement#example').attr('data-meta'); // jquery
```

Split it:

```
var astrVals = strTemp.split(" ");
```

Modify the third value:

```
astrVals[2] = "private";
```

Rejoin it:

```
strTemp = astrVals.join(" ");
```

Then set the value again:

```
$('myelement#example').attr('data-meta', strTemp); //jquery
oElem.setAttribute("data-meta", strTemp); // javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit with jQuery not with javascript:

First:

```
$('#anyID').removeAttr("meta-data")
```

After:

```
$('#anyID').attr("data-meta", "banana blue private")
```

Comment: OP didn't mention JQuery, it's not worth loading an entire library for this.

Comment: Thanks for your assumption, but i don't want to use jquery. As allready mentioned from Andrew it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few small functions that can make toggle like functionality.

The first one takes the string from attribute and splits it by spaces to make an array, the next one looks at the array to see if it contains what you want to toggle. Third and forth add and remove from the array and then join the array back together as a string with spaces.

I haven't added any error handling so if you try and remove an attribute that isn't there it will have issues but other than that is should get you started.

```js
// take contents of attribute and return an array
function arrFromAttr(selector, attribute) {
  return selector.getAttribute(attribute).split(" ");
}

// check the array and toggle the value
function toggleAttr(selector, attribute, value) {
  let attrs = arrFromAttr(selector, attribute);

  if (attrs.includes(value)) {
    removeAttr(selector, attribute, value)
  } else {
    addAttr(selector, attribute, value)
  }
}

// add to the array and set the attribute
function addAttr(selector, attribute, value) {
  let attrs = arrFromAttr(selector, attribute);

  attrs.push(value);
  selector.setAttribute(attribute, attrs.join(' '));
}

// remove from the array and set the attribute
function removeAttr(selector, attribute, value) {
  let attrs = arrFromAttr(selector, attribute);

  attrs.splice(attrs.indexOf(value), 1);
  selector.setAttribute(attribute, attrs.join(' '));
}

// toggle the attribute on button click
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleAttr(document.querySelector('[data-meta]'), "data-meta", "public");
})
```

```css
div[data-meta]:after {
  content: attr(data-meta)
}
```

```html
<div data-meta="banana blue public"></div>
<button>Toggle public</button>
```

I hope you find this helpful

---

If you're feeling fancy you can have your own polyfill you make a toggle function, though I wouldn't recommend doing something like this until you're confident in JS

```js
if (!(Element.prototype.toggleAttribute || Element.prototype.deleteAttribute || Element.prototype.addAttribute)) {
  Element.prototype.toggleAttribute = function(name, value) {
    let attrs = this.getAttribute(name).split(" ");
    if (attrs.includes(value)) {
      this.deleteAttribute(name, value)
    } else {
      this.addAttribute(name, value);
    }
  }

  Element.prototype.addAttribute = function(name, value) {
    let attrs = this.getAttribute(name).split(" ");
    attrs.push(value);
    this.setAttribute(name, attrs.join(' '));
  }

  Element.prototype.deleteAttribute = function(name, value) {
    let attrs = this.getAttribute(name).split(" ");
    attrs.splice(attrs.indexOf(value), 1);
    this.setAttribute(name, attrs.join(' '));
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('div').toggleAttribute('data-meta', 'public');
})
```

```css
div[data-meta]:after {
  content: attr(data-meta)
}
```

```html
<div data-meta="banana blue public"></div>
<button>Toggle public</button>
```

This code adds the functions to the native code so you can call the functions on a element rather than having to pass the element as an arguement.

Comment: Tank you for the work you put in this. I think it would work too, but for my project i have no need for functions that i can call from different places, so i will go with Seans easyer assumption.